# longer than and shorter than presumed

Tags: grammar

1. *Walking back home is gonna take longer than I presumed*
2. *Walking back home is gonna take shorter than I presumed*

I'm a bit confused here, is sentence #2 valid?
It certainly doesn't sound right.

If sentence #2 is invalid, how could i rephrase it?

Comment: Walking back home is gonna take longer than I **thought** – that's how I'd probably say it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence #2 is not what is the plain opposite of sentence #1. Not only that I'm afraid to say there is no direct opposite of "take longer" as in sentence no #1 - or anything I am aware of, that is. And hence, sentence no #2 is not correct.

You could say

> Walking back home wont take as long as you expected.
>
> Walking back home will be quicker than you expected

Comment: ...is gonna take less time... also